# Find same sequence of words in two strings

Tags: python-3.6

Before I start, I've searched for a long time trying to find a solution!

I'm trying to create a function that will return the longest matching sequence of words within 2 strings of different lengths.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
file_1 = 'i took a walk around the world to ease my troubled mind i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time i watched the world float to the dark side of the moon i feel there is nothing i can do yeah i watched the world float to the dark side of the moon after all i knew it had to be something to do with you i really dont mind what happens now and then as long as youll be my friend at the end if i go crazy then will you still call me superman if im alive and well will you be there holding my hand ill keep you by my side with my superhuman might kryptonite'
file_3 = 'when i was young i took a walk around the woods i found that i was both taller and smaller than the trees returning to my home i set out for the desert i journeyed for long days and nights my spirit left my body and i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time unburdened by physical form i watched the world float away from me and into the vast moonlight'
match = SequenceMatcher(None, file_1, file_3).find_longest_match(0, len(file_1), 0, len(file_3))
print(file_1[match.a: match.a + match.size])
```

This currently prints out "i took a walk around the wo"

What it should print is "i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time"

The alternative solution I've found is as below:

```
def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
answer = ""
len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
for i in range(len1):
    for j in range(len2):
        lcs_temp=0
        match=''
        while ((i+lcs_temp < len1) and (j+lcs_temp<len2) and string1[i+lcs_temp] == string2[j+lcs_temp]):
            match += string2[j+lcs_temp]
            lcs_temp+=1
        if (len(match) > len(answer)):
            answer = match
return answer
```

However, this also doesn't return what I want, as it prints "nd i left my body lying somewhere in the sands of time".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the auto junk setting? --> `SequenceMatcher(None, file_1, file_3, False)`

Comment: Thanks! that helps but it's still capturing the **"nd"** at the start for both strings e.g. "a**nd** i left" in the first string and "mi**nd** i left". I'll still keep playing around with it however, I just came across SequenceMatcher, so still trying to figure out the mechanics.